tkinter Label and field are very far away
I am having problems joining the label of tkinter to the gui. I am trying to put the asunto label on top left of the asunto textfield, although it was kind of achieved, they are far apart.
Intended GUI:

Actual GUI:

Here is the code:
def show_personalizado_page():
    
    hide_current_widgets()
    root.current_page = "personalizado"
    root.title("EvaMailer")
    root.geometry("800x600")

    # Add the logo
    try:
        logo_image = Image.open("EvaMailer.png")  # Update with your logo path
        logo_image = logo_image.resize((100, 100), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)  # Resize with proper resampling filter
        logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo_image)
        logo_label = tk.Label(root, image=logo)
        logo_label.image = logo  # Keep a reference to avoid garbage collection
        logo_label.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, columnspan=2)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error loading image: {e}")

    # Add the 'Regresar' button
    def go_back():
        show_main_page()

    regresar_button = tk.Button(root, text="Regresar", command=go_back)
    regresar_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='w')

    # Add the 'Columnas' listbox with a scrollbar
    columns_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    columns_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='ns', rowspan=2)

    columns_label = tk.Label(columns_frame, text="Columnas", font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'))
    columns_label.pack(anchor='w', padx=10)

    columns_listbox = tk.Listbox(columns_frame, height=15)
    columns_listbox.pack(side='left', fill='y')

    columns_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(columns_frame, orient='vertical', command=columns_listbox.yview)
    columns_scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

    columns_listbox.config(yscrollcommand=columns_scrollbar.set)

    # Add the 'Asunto' entry
    subject_label = tk.Label(root, text="Asunto", font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'))
    subject_label.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=(10, 2), sticky='w')
    
    subject_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=30)  # Adjust width for a smaller entry
    subject_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=(2, 10), sticky='ew')

    # Add the 'Cuerpo del Correo' text box
    body_label = tk.Label(root, text="Cuerpo del Correo", font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'))
    body_label.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='w')
    body_text = tk.Text(root, height=10, width=60)
    body_text.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='ew')

    # Add 'Enviar' button
    sendP_button = tk.Button(root, text="Enviar", command=lambda: print("Enviar button pressed"))  # Define button command
    sendP_button.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=(20, 10), sticky="e", padx=(10, 5))

    # Configure row and column weights to make the layout responsive
    root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)

    # Display the available variables as buttons
    display_csv_variables()


set sticky='new' for subject_entry.grid(), to stick that item to the "North" of the grid cell, as well as the east and west as you already have.

You need to learn and understand how rowspan and sticky opions work in grid(...).

To make the layout to look like what you want, you need to:

put logo_label at column 0 in order to center it horizontally
set sticky='nw' on regresar_button to put the button at the top-left corner
set rowspan=4 on columns_frame to minimize the gap between labels and entry boxes on the right side
set sticky='nsew' on body_text to expand the text widget

Below are the required changes:
def show_personalizado_page():
    ...
    try:
        ...
        logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, columnspan=2) # column=1 -> 0
    ...
    regresar_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='nw') # sticky='w' -> 'nw'
    ...
    columns_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='ns', rowspan=4)  # rowspan=2 -> 4
    ...
    body_text.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky='nsew') # sticky='ew' -> 'nsew'
    ...

Result:

To get better layout, suggest to comment the following two lines:
    #root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
    ...
    #root.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)

Result:

